# Nginx directive server_name fails sometimes

Tags: nginx, reverse-dns

I have 7 apps in a server with `nginx`, configured with server_name directive and listening port 80. Everything is working fine for me and many other people.

The thing is that 2 clients have a problem, because when I send a link to them, for example, aaa.com, they get the content of bbb.com.

I tried from many places and different computers but I couln't replicate the problem.

Any idea of what's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to stackoverflow, please put some configuration code that is related to the 2 websites in question from your **nginx.conf**, please make sure to mask any sensitive data like public IP or passwords in that configuration that you share

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem a long time ago. The problem was, that the clients were behind a proxy that would mess with the http headers, especially the host header. I would set up a log and log the host header for every request. That should give you an idea where the problem is.